# Object graph and Infinispan

Tags: infinispan

We have a large object graph in a Java application.
We would like to share the object graph between several nodes
We are now looking into Infinispan
The issue we are getting is when we are updating an object which is being referenced by several objects, Inifinispan is creating a new object and we are losing the reference to it from all other objects (which still point to the old object)

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when the cache is clustered, Infinispan has no way of preserving the references between objects in different cache entries.

You could try [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) on top of Infinispan, or implement something similar yourself: store the shared objects as separate entries (either in the same cache or in a different cache) and replace references to them with their cache keys on store, then replace cache keys with object references on load.